# How to enable/disable cookies programmatically for IE

Tags: internet-explorer, browser, cookies

I'd like to turn on cookies programmatically using a script or C# code. This needs to work at least for IE8 and IE9. Is there a way to do that. Is it a registry setting? Is there an API to do it?

I believe it is a per user setting, so ideally it would change the setting for the user the script/process is executing under.

Comment: The proper way to do this would be to use the URLMon Zone Manager APIs to set the desired values for each target security zone.